# How to tell which iOS font name is the "regular" version in a font family?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, nsattributedstring

I know that I can get a list of font family names with `[UIFont familyNames]` and iterate through the family's font names with `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]`. Is there any way to tell which font name represents the "normal" font? There isn't any consistency in the naming ("Roman", "Regular", or even the absence of a modifier adjective). I'm ultimately trying to change the font over a substring of an `NSAttributedString` while maintaining existing traits and decorations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I need to read the CoreText docs more closely. Passing in the font family name is enough if you use the right CoreText routines...

```
NSString *fontFamilyName = ...(font family name)...;
// Make a mutable copy of the attributed text
NSMutableAttributedString *workingAttributedText = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];

// Over every attribute run in the selected range...
[workingAttributedText enumerateAttributesInRange:self.selectedRange
    options:(NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions) 0
    usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        // get the old font
        CTFontRef oldFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)[attrs objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        // make a new one, with our new desired font family name
        CTFontRef newFontRef = CTFontCreateCopyWithFamily(oldFont, 0.0f, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)fontFamilyName);
        // Convert it to a UIFont
        UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithCTFont:newFontRef];
        // Add it to the attributed text
        [workingAttributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
    }];

// Replace the attributed text with the new version
[self setAttributedText:workingAttributedText];
```

If there is an easier way to do this, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't have to be a regular font in the list.  Some may only provide bold or only italic. This is why the list is often provided to the user to let them make the decision.